# How to listen for incoming messages from sockets of threads to update a Listview in android?

Tags: android, sockets, client, server

I am developing an android application in which I have to create a multiple clients connection with one server. At the server side I am creating a new thread for every client and it is working fine, but in the new created thread where I am listening for a messages from socket and updating a list view created in a fragment, it is not getting updated. Please help me to solve this issue.

```
public class ClientSocketHandler extends Thread {

 private static final String TAG = "ClientSocketHandler";
 //private Handler handler;
// private ChatManager chat;
 private InetAddress mAddress;
 InputStream dataInputStream=null;
 OutputStream dataOutputStream=null;
 static String msgToSend="";
 int i;
 char c;
 String newMsg="";
 Boolean flag=true;
 WiFiChatFragment frg;  
 Handler handler;
 public ClientSocketHandler(InetAddress groupOwnerAddress) {
 this.mAddress = groupOwnerAddress;
 //this.handler=handl;
  }
 @Override
 public void run() {
 Socket socket = new Socket();
 try {
 socket.bind(null);
 socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(mAddress.getHostAddress(),
 WiFiServiceDiscoveryActivity.SERVER_PORT), 5000);

 Log.d(TAG, "Launching the I/O handler");
    dataInputStream = socket.getInputStream();
    dataOutputStream = socket.getOutputStream();


    while (true) {
        while(flag){
            if((i=dataInputStream.read())!=1){

                frg.pushMessage(newMsg);
                newMsg="";
                flag=false;
            }
            else{
            c=(char)i;
            newMsg+=c;}

        }
    if(!msgToSend.equals("")){
             dataOutputStream.write(msgToSend.getBytes());
             dataOutputStream.flush();
             msgToSend = "";
            }

    }
 } catch (IOException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 try {
 socket.close();
 } catch (IOException e1) {
 e1.printStackTrace();
 }
 return;
 }
 }

 public static void sendMsg(String msg){
           msgToSend = msg;
 }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can happen of any of the following this is not handled.
1. Set the list adapted
2. Check that data is received on client and added to the data source.
3. Call the notifyDataSetChanged() after adding the data to data source for ListView.

Comment: List is in fragment.when connection gets established ,fragment starts and i am sending a message received from input stream of socket to a function of that fragment which will notify the adapter.

Comment: @Fari pass the Handler reference to  ClientSocketHandler thread in the constructor and send the message through the handler reference, and in Fragment you will get the sent message in handleMessage(Message msg) method. There you need to add this message to the List or ArrayList and then call the notifyDataSetChanged() to update the UI.

Comment: i am familiar with handle message method.but how can i pass the message from this thread to that handle message function??

Comment: One more question.how can i send message from that fragment,s text view to in the process of this thread to send it it out to server?

Comment: Modify you constructor to  public ClientSocketHandler(InetAddress groupOwnerAddress, Handler handle) {
 this.mAddress = groupOwnerAddress;
 this.handler=handle;
  }  \n  and use the following code to send the message from the thread through handler Message msgObj = handler.obtainMessage();
           Bundle b = new Bundle();
           b.putString("message", msg);
           msgObj.setData(b);
           handler.sendMessage(msgObj);

Comment: You can pass the message in through thread constructor if you are sending the message once from the Fragment.

Comment: thank you for your help.No i am not sending the message once ,so i can,t use constructor.i need to send the message every time when client types a message in text view and presses the Send button.Any other suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Create an Interface with a sendMessage(String msg) method which need to implemented by your thread. In this method you will get the message. OnClick of the button you can call this method with the textView text.

Comment: thanks for your help again.but i need to set this method to static but i am getting an error when i am setting this sendmessage(string msg) method to a static.is it not possible to declare a static methods in an interface?

Comment: i think i can not use this method in my code.because when i called this method from on click of button,it is a static call so i also need to set this method to static which is not allowed in interface.so any other possibility?